# Is there a way to prevent Hibernate envers to audit a database operation only once?

Tags: hibernate, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-envers

**Stack**:

1. `spring boot 2.7.15`
2. `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 2.7.15`
3. `spring-data-envers 2.7.15`

I have the following entity:

```
@Audited
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class MyUser{
}
```

With the auditor config class `JpaAuditingConfiguration`:

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(name = "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration")
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class JpaAuditingConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<Long> auditorAware(MyUserService myUserService ) {
        return myUserService::getCurrentUserId;
    }

}
```

And the `MyUserService` class:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyUserService {

    public Optional<Long> getCurrentUserId() {
         Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        if (principal instanceof OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal) {
           // logic here
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

My problem comes here: I have a Bean from our internal authorization/authentication framework which sets/enriches spring's `Authentication` object and it is triggered when the user logins in the UI. In this bean method, one entity is modified and persisted into the database:

```
 public Set<String> retrieveUserAuthorities(String username) {
        Optional<MyUser> userOptional = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        
        if (userOptional.isPresent()) {
            MyUser user = userOptional.get();

            // different setters for user
            myUserService.saveUser(user); // <--- here is the problem

            return ...
        }

      // ...
    }
```

**Problem:**

Basically, the problem is that the entity is persisted into the database **before** the `Authentication` object is set, thus getting a NPE when the audit flow is triggered and it reaches method `getCurrentUserId()` where `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` is null.

In my case, I want **only** this database operation **NOT TO BE persisted**, but others on that entity to be persisted, so removing `Audited` or `@EntityListeners` is not an option.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a simple null check before accessing the `principal` object should do the trick.

```
public Optional<Long> getCurrentUserId() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if (authentication != null && principal instanceof OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal) {
       // logic here
    }

    return Optional.empty();
}
```

It is not surprising to find the `authentication` object as `null` in spring security.

Comment: I wonder what's up with the down vote. If there is an entity which is audited and both a user and the system can edit it, when the system edits the entity and save it (maybe via a scheduled job), the authentication object is always 'null' 